# How to make certain JavaScript files load first?

Tags: javascript, web, loading, adsense, cloudflare

I'm using CloudFlare's Rocket Loader feature on my site and everything has improved. But the only problem is that due to CloudFlare's Rocket Loader feature, JavaScript is loaded at the end, and as a result my AdSense earnings are very much affected. Can anyone give me a perfect solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you omit them from your Rocket Loader and put them in the head of the document?

Comment: You could try giving it the `async` tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

Comment: I've already added the async tag but I want the website viewer to see the Google Ads first as soon as the page loads..

Answer (score 0):

ManoDestra was pointing you in the right direction.

Place the JS file that you are concerned about in the head of your document and add the data-cfasync="false" attribute to the script tag:

```
  <script data-cfasync="false" src="/javascript.js"></script>
```

See [this CloudFlare support document](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-) for full details

Comment: I'm already using the async tag. Ads were displayed. I just want the website viewer to see the Google Ads first as soon as the page loads..